# Why won't my Raphael JS animation loop?

Tags: javascript, animation, raphael

Hi there
I've made this animation using the Raphael framework. I want the star (logoStar) to spin indefinitely but it only runs once. Can anyone help? Thanks

```
window.onload = function () {
buildLogo();
}

var buildLogo = function () {
    var logo = Raphael("title",800,236);

    var logoStar = logo.path("M12.245 131.057L16.039 138.743L24.521 139.974L18.383 145.958L19.832 154.406L12.245 150.418L4.658 154.406L6.108 145.958L-0.03 139.974L8.452 138.743").attr({fill:"#fff",stroke:"none"});

    var starSpin = function () {
        logoStar.animate({rotation: "360"}, 5000, starSpin);
    }
    starSpin();
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
var starSpin = function () {
    logoStar.attr({rotation: 0}).animate({rotation: 360}, 5000, starSpin);
}
```

Animation from 360° to 360° looks like there no animation, so you need to reset rotation to zero before.

Comment: Yes! You're a legend Dmitry. Thanks very much. A gold (spinning) star for you.

Comment: After thousand hours tryingo to know whats wrong, i found out that the sintax is: transform:"r180" instead rotarion:180. Did the framework changed? Mind to edit the post to add this info?

Comment: If you're using version 2.0, this is no longer the correct answer. [This is](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11810719/7173), though.

Answer (score 6):

Since version 2 came out, the real way to have an infinitely looping animation is this:

```
var spin = Raphael.animation({transform: "r360"}, 2500).repeat(Infinity);
myElement.animate(spin);
```

`Infinity` is a [property in Javascript](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/core-javascript-reference/the-infinity-property), so don't enter it as a string.

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/VSAED/).

Answer (score 3):

Just a quick observation:

Looks like "Rotation" isn't part of the Atrr anymore since ver 2, so you can't use it in "animate", but you can replace that with "transform: "r" + (some degree)"..

eg:

```
 element.animate( {transform: "r" + (-90)}, 2000, 'bounce');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure, but I *think* that `starSpin` is not yet defined when you try to use it in the anonymous function.

Try changing:

```
var starSpin = function () {
    logoStar.animate({rotation: "360"}, 5000, starSpin);
}
starSpin();
```

to

```
function starSpin() {
    logoStar.animate({rotation: "360"}, 5000, starSpin);
}
starSpin();
```

**EDIT**
It turns out that that's not it at all -- I do not know what the problem *is* (hopefully someone who has more exposure to the Raphael library can help out there) but a kludgey-but-works solution is to clear the element in question before calling *the entire construct function in the callback* (I warned you it was kludgey).

**SEE:** http://jsfiddle.net/rbf5x/1/

Comment: That is not it. The function is defined. Your constructs are absolutely equal from the JavaScrupt language standpoint

Comment: @avok00 -- completely correct - I didn't think that was the problem, but I wasn't sure ... thanks for the heads up!

Comment: avok00, this is not a problem, of course, but those two constructs are not “absolutely equal”. :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Michael Mao, you should put

```
logoStar.animate({rotation: "360"}, 5000, starSpin);
```

in a loop.

But loops like this while(true) are not always a good idea. It will take too much CPU and some browsers may warn the user that a script is causing the page to run slowly. Maybe it is best to add a timeout before re-executing animate. Just try and see what works best ;)

Answer (score -2):

I am not very sure but what if you do this:

```
while(true){starSpin();}
```

It sounds like the method is only executed once, so it "spins" once...

Comment: The idea is that the animation accepts a callback for when it completes. The kind of infinite while loops like the one in your answer are not very common in client-side development, as they can cause the UI thread to hang.