# Issues having raphaeljs loop on animation

Tags: javascript, animation

I have a problem finding a way to loop my animation with raphaeljs.

I already saw this post

[Why won't my Raphael JS animation loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138644/why-wont-my-raphael-js-animation-loop)

however doing the same thing on my animation didn't work, which means its only executed once. My code is:

```
var ciclo = function() {
    var ex = easingx.value,
        ey = easingy.value;
        c.animate({
            "20%": {cy: 150, easing: ey,opacity: 100, callback: fade(0)},
            "40%": {cy: 250, easing: ey, callback: fade(1)},
            "60%": {cy: 250, easing: ey, callback: fade(2)},
            "80%": {cy: 150, easing: ey, callback: fade(3)},
            "90%": {cy: 50, easing: ey, callback: fade(4)},
            "100%": {cy: 50, easing: ey,opacity: 0, callback: fade(5)}
        }, 5000).animate({
            "20%": {cx: 50, easing: ex},
            "40%": {cx: 100, easing: ex},
            "60%": {cx: 200, easing: ex},
            "80%": {cx: 250, easing: ex},
            "90%": {cx: 200, easing: ex},
            "100%": {cx: 100, easing: ex}
            }, 5000,ciclo)
    };
ciclo();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, i already answered my question, when using key:value with animation there is no callback parameter!