# Raphaeljs resume animation after specific interval

Tags: path, jquery-animate, raphael, intervals, repeat

Open this JS Fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/NvQnG/2/). There are two paths which are animating. the dark blue bar animates according to minutes passed & the smaller green bar animates according to seconds. I want to loop this animations when they complete their animation. How can I do that?

JS Fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/NvQnG/2/)

```
window.onload= function aa () {

    var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 1900, 1900);
    var date = new Date;
    var hour = date.getHours();

    var mins = date.getMinutes();
    var secs = date.getSeconds();
    var secl = (60*60*1000)-(secs*1000);
    var minl = 60 - mins;
    var crx = 318*(mins/60);//sets width according to minutes passed when window is loaded

    var cry = 318*(secs/60);//sets width according to seconds passed when window is loaded
    var sec1 = (60-secs)*1000;

    var x=1;
    var y=1;

    var pathhh = "M"+x+","+y+" "+"h"+320+" "+"v"+270+" "+"h"+(-320)+"z";//bg
    var curbox = paper.path(pathhh).attr({fill:'315-#0299fa-#0473ba'});

    var pathh3 = "M"+(x+1)+","+(242+y)+" "+"h"+318+" "+"v"+27+" "+"h"+(-318)+"z";//black bar
    var cur1box = paper.path(pathh3).attr({fill:'black'});    

    var pathfm = "M"+(x+1)+","+(243+y)+" "+"h"+crx+" "+"v"+20+" "+"h"+"-"+crx+"z";//minutes bar
    var pathto = "M"+(x+1)+","+(243+y)+" "+"h"+318+" "+"v"+20+" "+"h"+(-318)+"z";
    var cu2box = paper.path(pathfm).attr({fill:'#03558b',stroke:'none'});
    cu2box.animate({path: pathto},secl);

    var patgfm = "M"+(x+1)+","+(265+y)+" "+"h"+cry+" "+"v"+4+" "+"h"+"-"+cry+"z"; //seconds bar
    var patgto = "M"+(x+1)+","+(265+y)+" "+"h"+318+" "+"v"+4+" "+"h"+(-318)+"z";
    var cu3box = paper.path(patgfm).attr({fill:'#0db1af',stroke:'none'});
    cu3box.animate({path: patgto},sec1);
};
```

​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138644/why-wont-my-raphael-js-animation-loop) is relevant, while not quite the same as yours. The question and the answer together contain the solution for your case: use the callback at the end of the animation, reset the path to the original and set the new animation.

Alternatively, use [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) to reset the animation every minute/hour.